# Loop a mongodb .find().toArray() using templating + ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

Have a basic AJAX web app running locally, where a Form POSTs data through Express/Node.js to MongoDB, and a button onClick responds in a rendering of the Mongo document(s) in a div-box.

**Using *[Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/)* for templating, onClick of the button only returns a right-brace to appear in the html div-box. console.log(returnValue); is listing the mongoDB documents though**

> }

**How can this be edited to loop through each MongoDB document?**

app.js

```
function getAllDOCs(res) {

    db.collection('dbCollectionName').find({}, {"_id":0}).toArray(function (err, docs) {

        console.log("this did getAllDocs");

        console.log("Got the DOCs: " + docs);

        var returnValue = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++)
        {
            if (returnValue == "")
            {
                returnValue = returnValue + JSON.stringify(docs[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                returnValue = returnValue + ", " + JSON.stringify(docs[i]);
            }
            console.log(docs[i]);
        }

        console.log(returnValue);

        res.render('wrapper', { allDOCs: returnValue });

    });
}
```

wrapper.html:

```
{% for go in allDOCs %}
_wrapperGet('{"getting":"{{ keyName }}"}')
{% endfor %}
```

index.html AJAX:

```
// handle FIND button clicks     
$('#findButton').click(function() {

  // make an ajax call
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: '_wrapperGet',
    data: $('#theForm').serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:9090",
        success: handleFINDbuttonResponse,
        error: handleFINDbuttonError
    });
});

function handleFINDbuttonResponse(data)
{
  // alert("Response! " + data);
  // parse the json string
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
  $('#theResponse').append( jsonObject.getting );
}
```

index.html:

```
<!-- For the Returned Fields -->
<div id="theResponse">

</div><!-- /.theResponse -->
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. `find` `toArray` sends an array to the callback. Not familiar with Swig -- but I'd guess you'd pass `res.render('wrapped', { allDocs: docs })` and then `for d in allDocs` in the template.

Comment: thanks @WiredPrairie, the { allDocs: docs } worked great.. Now responds with an array, though the array contains only [object Object]..? Thanks for the comment! Have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: `console.log` just shows them that way. Just try `console.log(docs[0])` to show one of the elements for example.